# OSX - Stop Bluetooth Low Battery Message

Tags: macos, keyboard, battery, bluetooth, touchpad

I've seen this asked before but never any solution.

When using the Apple wireless keyboard and trackpad a message pops up when the battery level gets down to 15%.  When you click the message away it comes back after 20 minutes or so.  Really annoying because 15% battery charge will still last me another 2 months or more.  Two months of constant reminders.

Is there any way to stop this?  Or at least to modify it's behaviour so that it only comes up when down to 5% and only reappears once per day?